# Mako avoid python imports

Tags: python, flask, mako

I am trying to create a template inheriting from another one using methods like `url_for`. If I delete `import` statement I get an error:

```
TypeError
TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not callable
```

Can I get rid of imports below?

main.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<%!
    from flask.helpers import url_for
    from flask.globals import request
%>
<html lang=en>

<head>
    <%block name="additional_scripts"/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<h1>Presence analyzer</h1>
    <ul>
        % for key, template in templates.items():
            <li
                % if request.path == '/statistics/{}/'.format(template['name']):
                    id="selected"
                % endif
            >
                <a href="${url_for('statistics_view', chosen=template['name'])}">${template['description']}</a>
            </li>
        % endfor
    </ul>
</html>
```

The inheriting file:

```
<%inherit file="main.html"/>

<%!
    from flask.helpers import url_for
%>

<%block name="additional_scripts">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart", "timeline"], 'language': 'pl'});
    </script>
    <script src="${url_for('static', filename='js/presence_weekday.js')}"></script>
</%block>
```

Calling view method:

```
@app.route('/statistics/<chosen>/')
def statistics_view(chosen):
    try:
        return LOOKUP.get_template(templates[chosen]['template']).render(templates=templates)
    except KeyError:
        abort(404)
```

And `main.py` file where app is created:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup

app = Flask(__name__)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
LOOKUP = TemplateLookup(directories=[os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),
                                                  'templates')])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another way for doing this. The problem was the way I rendered templates.

First I needed to create `MakoTemplates` instance in `main.py` file by adding this line and deleting `LOOKUP`:

```
MakoTemplates(app)
```

And then instead of using `LOOKUP.get_template...` I returned:

```
return render_template(templates[chosen]['template'], templates=templates)
```

This allowed me to delete these tags.

Answer (score 0):

The imports can not be avoided, `<%! %>` is so called [Module-level Blocks](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#module-level-blocks), it will be executed once when the template is loaded into memory. But it can not be shared between templates. just as how Python module works, everything need to be imported explictly before usage.